# Count observations greater than a particular value

Tags: r

I have a dataset `output` in R with a the variables `V1`,`V2`,`V3`,`V4`. How can I get the number of observations in `V4` that area greater than 2000?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using logical test and then sum over the values meeting the condition

```
sum(output$V4 > 2000)
```

Comment: We might want to add `na.rm=TRUE`

Answer (score 5):

if using a data.frame you could also use:

`nrow(output[output$V4>2000, ])`

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned above this is easier than people often realise:

Inputting "output$V4 >2000" will test which values are >2000 and output TRUE or FALSE, as > is a logical comparison

As a result you can SUM over this to find the number of values which are TRUE (>2000), ie Count. While you may have been expecting this input to SUM the actual values themselves